# Who can identify this object?

Tags: ios, ios7

Hi I am struggling to identify what kind of object this app is using to populate the fields below, it resizes automatically depending on the amount of text and there is no scroll for each field only for all together. I already tried Labels, Text Views and did not work.

The developer reply, he uses "CUSTOM UIVIEW" any idea how to do this? thanks

[image]

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/nbqezb.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CUSTOM UIView, you can check how to make it on:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view
That is a great tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that they're using a `UITableView` and calculating the `UITableViewCell` heights on-the-fly based on the text in each row.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Calculate the height of the row, based on the string for this indexPath
}
```

On iOS 7, you can use the following `NSString` method to determine the height of a string in a given rectangle:

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context;
```

On iOS 6 and earlier, you can use:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
```

Comment: I will try both... and let you know.. Tks

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with custom cells, and they're adjusting the cell height based on the text. I use this code to adjust cell height in my apps:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.questions.count == 0) return 44;
    CGFloat labelNeededHeight = [self.questions[indexPath.row][@"title"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:19.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 68, 5000)].height;
    return MAX(labelNeededHeight, 44);
}
```

You need to put your own values in the `constrainedToSize` parameter, the first one in `CGSizeMake` is the width of the label in the cell, and the second (5000 in my case) is the maximum allowable height for the cell.

Comment: I will try both... and let you know.. Thx